# How to get a set $E$ such that $0<\mu(E\cap I)<\mu(E)$ for all interval $I$?

Tags: measure-theory

The solution of problem 6 (page 3) [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/STANFORD/STANF205-11/hwk3-sol.pdf) uses a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $0<\mu(E\cap I)<\mu(E)$ for all interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. Could someone give me an example of a set that satisfies this condition?

($\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a fat Cantor set of diameter $1/3^n$ and measure $1/6^n$ about each rational $q_n$ in some enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: Does $0<\mu(E\cap I)<\mu(E)$ for all $I$ imply $0<\mu(E^c\cap I)<\mu(E)$ for all $I$? If so, how can we see it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be $<\mu(I)$?

Comment: The motivation for the question in comment above is the answer in the following link. http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2009;task=show_msg;msg=2677.0001 I thought that the solution in the first link were the same that the solution in the second.

Comment: Actually I'm able to solve the problem 6 (first link) if a set $E$ such that $0<\mu(E\cap I)$ and $0<\mu(E^c\cap I)$ for all $I$ exists. Is there any set with this property?

Comment: Yes, the link uses mu(I). Then the answer is easy; $\mu(I)=\mu(E\capI)+\mu(E^c\capI)$, so if one is positive but not all of mu(I), so is the other.

Comment: Sorry. You are right.

Comment: IS the example (generalized Cantor set) given in this link correct? http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2009;task=show_msg;msg=2677.0001.0001.0001

Comment: Yes, see this link, first page:www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/6210/ps2-solutions.pdf